# scala: sum of squares of every even-positioned digits starting from 2nd position

Tags: scala

I can use the following code to sum up squares of every digits. how could it be changed to only do it for even-positioned digits starting from 2nd position ?

```
var sum:Int = num.toString.map{ _.asDigit }.map(x => x*x).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want every even-positioned value, one way of doing that is with `grouped` and `head`.
2. To start at the second digit, take the tail of the list before grouping.

```
val sum = num.toString.map{ _.asDigit }.tail.grouped(2).map(_.head).map(x => x*x).sum
```

See it working [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nCYECBSzRKCf0E3veGnyHQ).

Comment: yes even positioned, starting at second digit. so for 1623, we should get 45

Comment: Ah I put the `.tail` in the wrong place, my bad. I've fixed my answer to reflect that (and updated the Scastie link).

Answer (score 1):

Sum of squares of even digits from the right - tail recursion

```
def sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(num: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec def impl(num: Int, idx: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (num == 0) acc
    else if (idx % 2 == 0) impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc + ((num % 10) * (num % 10)))
    else impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc)
  }
  impl(num, 1, 0)
}

assert(sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(123456) == 5*5 + 3*3 +1*1)
```

Sum of squares of even digits from the left - tail recursion

```
def sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(num: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec def impl(num: Int, idx: Int, acc: Int, length: Int = -1): Int = {
    if (length % 2 == 0) {
      impl(num / 10, idx, acc + ((num % 10) * (num % 10)))
    } else {
      if (num == 0) acc
      else if (idx % 2 == 0) impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc + ((num % 10) * (num % 10)))
      else impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc)
    }
  }
  impl(num, 1, 0, (Math.log10(num) + 1).toInt)
}

assert(sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(123456) == 2*2 + 4*4 + 6*6)
```

Sum of squares of even digits from the left - iterators

```
def sumOfEvenDigitsIterators(num: Int): Int =
  num
    .toString
    .iterator
    .map(_.asDigit)
    .grouped(2)
    .collect{ case ArraySeq(_, b) => b }
    .map(x => x * x)
    .sum
```

---

Benchmark: `sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 10 -f 2 -t 1 bench.So59627557"`

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So59627557 {
  def _sumOfEvenDigitsIterators(num: Int): Int =
    num
      .toString
      .iterator
      .map(_.asDigit)
      .grouped(2)
      .collect{ case ArraySeq(_, b) => b }
      .map(x => x * x)
      .sum

  def _sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(num: Int): Int = {
    @tailrec def impl(num: Int, idx: Int, acc: Int, length: Int = -1): Int = {
      if (length % 2 == 0) {
        impl(num / 10, idx, acc + ((num % 10) * (num % 10)))
      } else {
        if (num == 0) acc
        else if (idx % 2 == 0) impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc + ((num % 10) * (num % 10)))
        else impl(num / 10, idx + 1, acc)
      }
    }

    impl(num, 1, 0, (Math.log10(num) + 1).toInt)
  }

  val num: Int = (math.random * 100000000).toInt
  @Benchmark def sumOfEvenDigitsIterators: Int = _sumOfEvenDigitsIterators(num)
  @Benchmark def sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion: Int = _sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion(num)
}
```

results

```
[info] Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
[info] So59627557.sumOfEvenDigitsIterators      thrpt   20   2033487.342 ± 187156.764  ops/s
[info] So59627557.sumOfEvenDigitsTailRecursion  thrpt   20  27431255.610 ± 835429.506  ops/s
```

Tail-recursive solution seems to have more than 10x throughput than iterators-based solution.

Comment: This is a nice solution and I'm rewriting mine to add an example that goes in this direction. However, the original code took digits from the left, so I guess that's what OP wanted. Furthermore, he explicitly asked 0th item to not be kept, suggesting he wanted the index to be 0-based. The output for 123456 would then be 3^2 + 5^2 = 9 + 25 = 34.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to keep only even-positioned is to use `zipWithIndex`:

```
// Your initial code
def squareDigitsSummation(n: Int): Int =
  n.toString.map{ _.asDigit }.map(x => x*x).sum

def squareEvenPositionedDigitsSummation(n: Int): Int =
  n.toString.view.
    tail.
    map(_.asDigit).
    zipWithIndex.
    collect { case (n, i) if i % 2 != 0 => n * n }.
    sum

assert(squareDigitsSummation(1234) == 30)
assert(squareEvenPositionedDigitsSummation(1234) == 9)
```

Please note that `zipWithIndex` is 1-based, so I had to somewhat counter-intuitively negate the `filter` predicate to keep odd-indexed pairs (I assumed you wanted to have 0-based indexes, given you explicitly mentioned you didn't want the 0th element to be kept).

Comment: `filter` + `map` === `collect`.

Comment: sum of even positioned, starting at second digit. so for 1623, we should get 45

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex?

```
val num = 24874
var sum: Int = "\\d{2}".r
  .findAllIn(num.toString)
  .map(_.last.asDigit)
  .map(v => v * v)
  .sum
```

Comment: This works under the assumption OP wanted this to work with 1-based indexes. I believe the original intent was to have 0-based indexes (i.e. the third and fifth characters - 8 and 4 in this case - are even-positioned and have to be squared and summed).

Comment: @stefanobaghino, obviously it doesnt really matter, just change _.last to _.first, and it is the only solution out of all provided which should work in both cases without big changes

Comment: but "second position" means indexes 1, 3, 5